# Arm loop code optimization for calculating mean standard deviation

Tags: objective-c, c, arm, optimization

I want to improve some code which is using 25% of my app CPU, the code is the next:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
unsigned f = *p++;
sum += f;
sqsum += f*f;
}
```

I made some arm code but it is not working, even not compiling, which is the next:

```
void loop(uint8_t * p , int *  sum ,int * qsum)
{

__asm__ volatile("vld4.8 {d0}, [%0]!      \n"
                 "mov r4, #0              \n" 
                 "vmlal.u8 [%1]!, [%1]!, d0 \n"
                 "vmull.u8 r4, d0 , d0    \n"
                 "vmlal.u8 [%2]!, [%2]!, r4\n"  
                 :
                 : "r"(p), "r"(sum), "r"(qsum)
                 : "r4"
                 );
}
```

Any help?

Here is the my function to improve:

```
void calculateMeanStDev8x8(cv::Mat* patch, int sx, int sy, int& mean, float& stdev)
    {
    
    unsigned sum=0;
    unsigned sqsum=0;
    
    for (int j=0; j< 8; j++) {
        const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)(patch->data + (j+sy)*patch->step + sx); //Apuntador al inicio de la matrix
        
      //The code to improve
      for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
      unsigned f = *p++;
    sum += f;
    sqsum += f*f;
    }
    }
    
    mean = sum >> 6;
    int r = (sum*sum) >> 6;
    stdev = sqrtf(sqsum - r);
    
    if (stdev < .1) {
        stdev=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that you are going to optimize that loop by hand better than what the compiler can do. Have you taken a look at the assembly generated by the compiler?

Comment: Better to use intrinsics for this in the first instance rather than raw asm - much easier to get it working and performance will be close to that possible with hand-optimised asm.

Comment: @zennehoy there actually is a lot of potential for this to turn out as a true optimization. But then again, you are totally right that the OP should compare the result to what the compiler generates. For a start, I would however play with NEON instincts.

Comment: Have you measured that you actually have a bottleneck?  That is a short loop counter (0 to 7)

Comment: This loop is inside two loops, thats because is using so much CPU, but the other loops are doing a lot of stuff so I not trying to improve all the code.

Comment: I will try to look at the assembly generated code, but I don´t know now how to do it. anyone pointing me how to do it?

Comment: @Gustavo "the other loops are doing a lot of stuff" - a very good indicator that you are optimizing in the wrong place. You have to optimize the stuff that takes a lot of time, not the stuff that looks easy to optimize.

Comment: @Gustavo How to generate assembly code depends on the compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @zennehoy I am using the LLVM compiler 1.6 with the Xcode, also I know  that this loop takes a lot of time because instruments is giving me that the cpu time and this loop takes 44% of all the time.

Comment: @Gustavo I believe the compiler switch you are looking for then is `-S`

Comment: @zennehoy I tried to find what compiler switch "-S" means with google but I don`t know whats thease, could you please explain me what means? thanks!!!

Comment: @Gustavo - `gcc -S -o - yourfile.c` obviously adding in other bits you need to make it compile or changing `gcc` for your compiler of choice.

Comment: Thanks, I forget macosx is unix XD

Comment: your code sample is incomplete. what are the types for sum and sqsum?

Comment: Is it actually your intention to find the mean and stddev of 64 character-sized elements?

Comment: Yes it is, do you know a better way to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That loop is a perfect candidate for NEON optimization. You can fit your 8 unsigned integers into a single NEON register. There is no "sum all elements of a vector" instruction, but you can use the pairwise add to compute the sum of the 8 elements in 3 steps. Since we can't see the rest of your application, it's hard to know what the big picture is, but NEON is your best bet for improving the speed. All recent Apple products support NEON instructions and in XCode you can use the NEON intrinsics mixed with your C++ code.

Comment: I have just edited the question, so you now are able to se the function. thanks!!!